# .val assign to variable on submit of form

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I make this variable calculation work when the user hits the submit button?

```
var size = $("#size").val();

<input id="size" />
<button type="Submit">Calculate!</button>
```

Should take value of the input and store it in variable = size

Is it possible to then output this back to the user on the page without reloading after submit using jQuery only?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8pEp2/1/)

Comment: You could use the .html function to place the output in a div without reloading the page. But what is your goal? Outputting something the user just entered?

Comment: Is this all in a form?

Comment: @EmeryFramboise doing some simple maths based on the user input. I just wanted to get the hang of outputting it to check it's working, then do the maths. It will output two measurements. First measurement (width) = same as they put in (seems silly I know.) Second measurement (length) = (size/2)*5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach an event handler to the `submit` event of the form.  The event handler should call `preventDefault()` on the event to prevent the form from submitting.

### Basic Example

**HTML**

```
<form>
<input id="size" />
<button type="Submit">Calculate!</button>
</form>
<div id="output"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var size;
$("form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();  //prevents form from submitting
    size = $("#size").val();
    $("#output").text(size);
});
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/NKq6L/

---

### Using Fiddle Code

**Javascript**

```
$("#cushionCalculator").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var size = $("#size").val();
    $("#output").text(size);
});
```

**Fiddle Using Your Code:** http://jsfiddle.net/8pEp2/2/

Comment: This great, quick Q if I want to add 3 to the user input number, how do I do that? Tried this but with 10 I get 103 instead of 13 if that makes sense $("#outputWidth").text(size + 3);

Comment: `parseInt(size) + 3` `size` is currently being treated as a `String` you must convert it to a number. See: http://jsfiddle.net/8pEp2/4/

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
$('button').submit(function() {
  var size = $('#size').val();
  // Do whatever you want with size
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I like is to serialize the whole form, this way:

your HTML form:

```
<form id=myform>
<input name="Size" id="size" value="hello world" />
<input name="somethingelse" id="somethingelse" />
<button type="Submit">Calculate!</button>    
</form>
```

now your srcipt:

```
var obj = $('myform').serialize();

alert(obj.Size);
alert(obj.somethingelse)
```

size alert will display 'hello world' or what ever value it has
hope it helps!